# C# question - make form visible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I made 2 forms in C# visual studio.
How can I make one form invisible and another visible (Have done this in visual basic only before)

I guess Syntax should be similar.

Comment: if you've done this in VB.NET, the code should be virtually identical. It's all the same classes and namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, VB.NET will pre-create the forms for you, and you only have to call Show(). In C#, you will have to create all but the MainForm.

```
// in a buttonClick on Form1
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
```

This will create a new instance each time you click the button.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Form.Visible` property, or the `Form.Show()` method.

Answer (score 3):

To hide and show a form, use the Form.Visible property:

```
Form.Visible = true;
Form.Visible = false;
```

There's also methods that do the same thing (these are designed to be used with the [MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) delegate):

```
Form.Show();
Form.Hide();
```

Comment: I still have troubles getting this to work.

Here is what I tried:

            Form2.ActiveForm.Show();
            //Form2.Hide();
            Form2.ActiveForm.Activate();
            Form2.ActiveForm.Visible = true;

I don't know why, but I need to use ActiveForm method or I get errors.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the property Visible of the class Form.